# Mandar POST en php

Tags: php, variables, post

Tengo un fichero php (crtEnfr.php) al que le envio un POST desde otro fichero (enfForm.php) para que imprima un resultado en una tabla...

Pero me gustaria mandar el mismo valor del POST que está en crtEnfr.php a otro fichero (print_view.php)

Se que tiene que ser algo muy básico, pero, ¿Como puedo hacerlo?

Saludos

Comment: Hola. Si lo que quieres es enviar desde el fichero `crtENfr.php` un valor a `print_view.php` podrías hacerlo desde la URL usando `GET`.

Comment: Hola, el valor/variable lo tengo en: $_POST['createDiv']; si me dices como puedo hacerlo asi te lo agradeceria

Comment: Sería de ayuda saber que hace cada fichero y poder ver el código relevante de los mismos para poder darte una respuesta de calidad.

Comment: Creo que no es necesario el código completo (Son muchas lineas) para la petición... Solo os pido como "reenviar" una variable guardada en POST a otro fichero.

Comment: Teniendo el POST en `crtEnfr.php` puedes pasarlo a `print_view.php` por GET o por SESSION.

Answer (score 1):

Fichero `crtEnfr.php`:

```
<?php

session_start();

$_SESSION['post'] = $_POST;
```

Fichero `print_view.php`:

```
<?php

session_start();

$post = $_SESSION['post'];

var_dump($post);
```